Was there a time in Jewish history when Tefillin wasn’t commonplace?
I’ve heard an (unsourced) claim that there was a time in Jewish history when Tefillin was not available (or at least not practiced by the majority of Jews).
Can anyone source (or debunk) this?
And, if true, was it renewed from scratch or revived from a minority tradition?

I just came across this very related question: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/139927/anti-karaite-reactionary-basis-for-increased-tefillin-observance . I’ll let the powers that be decide whether it’s a duplicate.

I've heard that the Sema"k ran a campaign to restore kiyum mitzvat tefillin, as there was then a safek whether to rule like Rashi or his grandson, Rabbeinu Tam. The result was that people were using neither

I cited one relevant source here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/118656/20472

@Harel13 That’s a fascinating essay you wrote there, and I definitely hope to eventually read the whole thing. My question, however, is more about the continuity of the tradition of making Tefillin than their popularity in specific communities.

@Harel13 My agenda here is to find a mitzvah that was revived post-prophecy through textual means, as opposed to tradition, that can be compared to the modern revival of techeiles.

Not sure I understand. Are you asking whether there's evidence (or evidence against) that Jews forgot how to make tefillin and then figured out how to make them again on their own?

@Harel13 Exactly.
